# Totaling Expenses by Employee ID with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SELECT query to generate a specific output file that will be sent between systems relating to company expense reports. I am using data from two tables and am needing to generate a total value each employee owes the company. My query is similar to the following:

```
SELECT emp.Employee_ID,
       invoice.Date,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Invoice_Amount from invoice where....) as Amount_Owed
FROM employee as emp
INNER JOIN invoice_data as invoice
    on invoice.employee_id = emp.employee_id
GROUP BY emp.Employee_ID, invoice.Date
```

Now obviously I know there is something wrong with this query, because I am getting results such as the following:

```
Employee_ID | Date     | Amount_Owed
-------------------------------------
1000001     | 20190904 | 15.00
1000001     | 20190905 | 15.00
1000001     | 20190906 | 15.00
1000025     | 20190904 | 25.99
1000025     | 20190905 | 25.99
1000025     | 20190906 | 25.99
```

How do I change my query so that I can essentially get the invoice total for each employee by date? I have tried change the SELECT in the subquery to `SELECT sum(Invoice_Amount from invoice where....)`, but then I always get errors from SSMS saying that it returns more than a single record so that does not seem to be valid. That same error also prevents me from just doing a SELECT without the "TOP 1" in the subquery.

This is probably a fairly simple issue, but I have spun my wheels too long without any successful attempts, so I would appreciate suggestions as to how I can get the data I want.

Comment: Not sure why you are using a subquery here. This looks like a typical aggregate...hint SUM

Comment: @SeanLange I am using a subquery because I have a long list of conditions in a WHERE clause that a record needs to meet in order to be included in the SUM.

Comment: You can easily utilize a case expression to include a row or not in the aggregate. This is known as conditional aggregation and is very common.

Comment: I don't think `....` is valid SQL -- most times it helps to see the actual SQL to understand the issue.

Comment: @Hogan I know it's not valid SQL, but I don't want to copy/paste my exact code as I do not want to expose any actual data, and I do not believe the issue lies with the WHERE clause.

Comment: how exactly would pasting SQL expose data?

Comment: @SeanLange I moved my WHERE clause to the main query instead of being in a subquery, and then did a simple SUM like you suggested and that did the trick. Thank you for your help! I knew this would be a simple fix, but I had been looking at it too long to see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't a simple aggregation work?

```
SELECT e.Employee_ID, id.Date,
       SUM(id.Invoice_Amount) as Amount_Owed
FROM employee e INNER JOIN
     invoice_data id
     on id.employee_id = e.employee_id
GROUP BY e.Employee_ID, id.Date
```

Comment: I have spent way too long on this query for this simple answer to be the key, but this did work. For some reason I was under the assumption that moving my WHERE clause from the subquery to the main query would return invalid results. Thank you for taking my question seriously and providing a useful answer.